# How to stop training some specific weights in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm just beginning to learn TensorFlow and I have some problems with it.In training loop I want to ignore the small weights and stop training them. I've assigned these small weights to zero. I searched the tf API and found `tf.Variable(weight,trainable=False)` can stop training the weight. If the value of the weight is equal to zero I will use this function. I tried to use `.eval()` but there occurred an exception ValueError("Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default ". I have no idea how to get the value of the variable when in training loop. Another way is to modify the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()`, but I don't know how to do it. Has anyone implemented this code yet or any other methods suggested? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to apply regularization to the weights?

There is an `apply_regularization` method in the API that you can use to accomplish that.

See: [How to exactly add L1 regularisation to tensorflow error function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706379/how-to-exactly-add-l1-regularisation-to-tensorflow-error-function)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't get the hang of this method. Can this method stop updating zero weight? I want to implement a pruning network and stop training the zero weight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any use-case for stopping training of some variables, probably it's not what you should do.

Anyway, calling `tf.Variable()` (if I got you right) is not going to help you, because it's called just once when the graph is defined. The first argument is `initial_value`: as the name suggests, it's assigned only during initialization.

Instead, you can use [tf.assign](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) like this:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
  assign_op = var.assign(0)
  session.run(assign_op)
```

It will update the variable during the session, which is what you're asking for.